# Handling page refresh in backbone + spring rest component based application

Tags: spring, backbone.js

I have tow applications deployed on 2 different tomcat servers. 
first application completely consists of .js and .css code prepared using backbone.js and application 2 consists of a Spring MVC,Rest application which handles the rest calls made by the backbone application

I am facing a problem in this scenario, which is at the time of login when a request is send to app-2 , response is send consisting of all the login session related details in a Json object. After the response is recieved, all the received details is stored in backbone model object and a view called Welcome is rendered accordingly.

But what if i do a page refresh on welcome page, will the details in the model persist. If yes then no issue but if no then what should be done ???

Answer (score 0):

No, the JavaScript models will not persist after a page refresh. Generally, the way I've seen it resolved is having two authentication calls in app-2: One to log in, and another to check if logged in. This way, when the page loads, you can quickly make a request to check if the user has already logged in. If so, then forward to the app. If not, let the user log in.